# How do I find the center and radius of my circularly distributed data?

Tags: estimation, geometry

I'm analysing data that was collected in an optics experiment. The measurements are roughly in the form of a ring. In an ideal world the center of this ring would coincide with the origin, but due to imperfections in the alignment the measurements are usually shifted a bit. To fit the data with our models, I need a way to find good estimations of the radius of the ring and of the position of the center.

A complicating factor is that the rings we measured usually aren't completely rotationally symmetric, in that one some parts of the ring are more accented and others are less so.

The following plot is of one of the data sets. As you can see, the center of the ring is slightly shifted upwards, the ring is a bit noisey and the left side of the ring is more pronounced than the right.

[image: A sample plot]

**Question**: Is there an analysis technique or some transform that I can use to estimate the location of the center and the radius of the ring? Preferably something that can be automated easily.

Comment: Rick Wicklin had a recent blog post on just this probelm, [Fit a circle to data](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/06/08/fit-circle.html).